# Ubuntu 12.10 Sendmail cannot connect ip:25

Tags: ubuntu, ssmtp

I have recently set up an old box with Ubuntu 12.10 and LAMP running on it. I am using php as my cron jobs and would like to send an email as part of the scripts. I have set up sSMTP / Sendmail instead of a full mail server because there is already an Outlook 2010 server running on the network and do not want to cause any issues with that in regards to receiving mail.

I have input the correct details into ssmtp.conf but I keep getting the error: 'Cannot open ip:25'

In the conf file I believe it is the mailhub setting, within this setting I have tried using the local and external IP address for the exchange server, I have also tried using the domain mail.*.co.uk

I have searched and searched but cannot find any help in regards to this problem, everyone seems to forward there smtp to google but the data I will email will be private and would much rather do it locally for security reasons.

Thank you so much for reading,

Comment: Can you telnet at the Exchange Server's port 25? Have you checked whether the Exchange configuration accepts connections from this machine?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
The configuration does allow connections, I was originally having authentication issues but that is now sorted. Yes I can telnet into it. I have tried using'UseTLS=Yes' which the server accepts and 'AuthMethod=LOGIN' + other variants like CRAM-MD5.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use TLS then you will need to change the port to 587 or 465

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have just tried using those ports but unfortunately no luck. There was a long delay but the error was again the same as above, 'cannot open..' . I have added the Ubuntu IP address to the allowed servers/users list on the exchange management console but that didnt work either. I'm really scratching my head with this one. I have looked at a full email server but I cant afford any interference with the Exchange server.

Comment: OK , try to eliminate the possible source of the error ... try sendemail with a gmail account , 
'sendEmail -f "the sender <sender@gmail.com>" -t the reciver@somedomain.com -u "This is subject" -m "This is body" -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu sender@gmail.com -xp Somepassword -o tls=yes' 

if it worked then it is your exchange config

Comment: Thanks @BluesRhythm, I have just tried this but there were multiple issues, I had to install sendemail then there were authentication issues with the tls, all in all I have had no luck but will keep trying :)

Comment: You can also try with ssmtp This configuration is valid and i use it
http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Gmail_and_sSMTP